# Possible memory leak in c3p0 in Hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, memory-leaks, c3p0

We use c3p0 as the pooling library in Hibernate with the configuration below. We suspect that there might be a memory leak in this library. We dump the memory heap of the application and it shows one object of type "com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GlobalMaxOnlyStatementCache" uses 2.2GB memory (61.6% of all) and it continues to grow until it runs out of memory. This class is used to cache PreparedStatements as far as I understand it. Our configuration uses 100 for this value, which means at most 100 statements should be cached.

```
configuration
    .setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.max_size", "25")
    .setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.min_size", "2")
    .setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.initial_pool_size", "2")
    .setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.timeout", "3600")
    .setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.max_statements", "100")
    .setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period", "300")
    .setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment", "2")
    .setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.maxConnectionAge", "3600")
    .setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.numHelperThreads", "6")
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: hi. a few quick questions: 1) what version of c3p0 are you using? 2) can you monitor your application by JMX? c3p0 reports extensive information about its statement cache there, and that information might be helpful; 3) what dbms/jdbc driver are you using? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can really be a bug. I suggest to report your issue [here](https://github.com/swaldman/c3p0/issues).

Three hints:

1. Statement caching is by default **disabled** in c3p0. I think you can guess why.
2. c3p0 is too easy to misconfigure.
3. c3p0 is a (quite) mature library but unfortunately is also far from being optimal choice for JDBC connection pooling nowadays. I really recommend you trying out faster and more reliable [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP).

In my opinion, HikariCP is also far more predictable and simpler to use than c3p0. Of course, you also have other connection-pooling libraries: DBCP, Tomcat pooling, BoneCP, Proxool etc. You may try some of them and pick the one that suits your app.

So basically you have two options, turn-off JDBC statement caching in c3p0 and wait for a fix (or fix it independently and create Pull Request) or try some alternative.

Comment: that statement caching isn't enabled by default is straight out of the JDBC 3 specification of transparent Statement pooling configured with a maxStatements parameter, whatever else you might be suggesting.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The only concern I have with turning it off is the performance hit. Although the c3p0 doc suggests to profile the application for the user of the caching. 

Also thanks for your link. I posted an issue at here: https://github.com/swaldman/c3p0/issues/61

Comment: @SteveWaldman sorry, I didn't know that. Thanks for that hint.

Comment: I finally disabled the statement caching and the memory leak problem went away. I didn't notice any performance issues by disabling the cache.